# Phonegap plugins not working on first run

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I created a PhoneGap iOS app and for some weird reason all of my plugins (Inappbrowser, SMSBuilder & SocialSharing) dont work on first run of app after installed. only after closing the app and opening again, everything works correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: That indeed seems strange. Have you tried it multiple times to see if you get this behaviour consistently? Are you waiting for the Cordova ready event before invoking any of the plugin code?

Comment: OMG! i think thats it, can you refrence me to a link with a code snippet for waiting for the cordova ready event?

do i have to add it to every change?

Comment: The "deviceready" event is invoked when the device API's have loaded. Once the device API's have loaded, you should not need to use the deviceready event again during the life of the application (not until the next time the app is launched).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should be using a Single Page Architecture for PhoneGap, not doing so is a sure way to get rejected from AppStore anyway.

You don't want people to sit through load times between webpages, check out Handlebars.js for an easy way to do this + you should check out this tutorial which covers the basic use of SPA/PhoneGap. http://coenraets.org/blog/phonegap-tutorial/

I would advice *against* JQuery Mobile as that is noticeably slower on underperforming devices, and also one of those things that does not differentiate your app from a simple webpage.

Answer (score 1):

From here: [PhoneGap API Documentation: deviceready](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready).

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use device APIs
}
```

"This event is essential to any application. It signals that Cordova's device APIs have loaded and are ready to access."

Comment: This is so weird, now deviceready fires only on index file and not other files of the app (ONLY ON THE FIRST RUN). after closing the app and starting again, deviceready fires on every page. :/

Comment: I think it only needs to be fired once in the index page. From then on, even if you change page the PhoneGap and device API's should still be accessible.

Comment: No it doesnt, it even says in the console that phonegap is resetting plugins due to page load :q

Comment: i know but it doesnt arghh guess i'm gonna have to re-write the hole thing with jquery mobile to make it all into a single html file.