# Cordova plugins doesn't work on first build

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic/Cordova App. And for some strange reason, when I first build the app. Plugins don't load.
But When I rebuild the app, it starts working again.

It is somehow related to the issue here [Phonegap plugins not working on first run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613557/phonegap-plugins-not-working-on-first-run), but not exactly the same.

```
[25/01, 11:18 a.m.] Inder: These are the errors that I get when i build and run the app
[25/01, 11:23 a.m.] Inder: 2018-01-25 11:18:37.640001+0100 Admiral[6647:207621] ERROR: Plugin 'Device' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2018-01-25 11:18:37.640121+0100 Admiral[6647:207621] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 159] FAILED pluginJSON = ["Device1680548736","Device","getDeviceInfo",[]]
2018-01-25 11:18:37.640254+0100 Admiral[6647:207621] ERROR: Plugin 'File' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2018-01-25 11:18:37.640362+0100 Admiral[6647:207621] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 159] FAILED pluginJSON = ["File1680548737","File","requestAllPaths",[]]
2018-01-25 11:18:37.640482+0100 Admiral[6647:207621] ERROR: Plugin 'NetworkStatus' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2018-01-25 11:18:37.640567+0100 Admiral[6647:207621] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 159] FAILED pluginJSON = ["NetworkStatus1680548738","NetworkStatus","getConnectionInfo",[]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to access the plugin which are not been added into the DOM. A simple solution is to load your `cordova.js` and `index.js` (Which has deviceready listener in it)

**Don't**

```
<!-- some scripts -->
<script src="scripts/some.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/somthing.js"></script> <!-- This JS trying to access device object created by cordova.js -->


<script src="scripts/cordova.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/index.js"></script> <!-- has deviceready event in it -->
<body>
<!-- content -->
```

**Do**

```
<script src="scripts/cordova.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/index.js"></script> <!-- has deviceready event in it -->

<!-- some scripts -->
<script src="scripts/some.js"></script>     
<script src="scripts/somthing.js"></script> <!-- This JS trying to access device object created by cordova.js -->
<body>
<!-- content -->
```

The best and optimised solution would be to load scripts at last in body. but due to some reason if you are loading them in head you need to check the order of that script